# Rendering pins of categories to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, categories, scaffold

I am a newbie and I am working on a scaffold category for pins on a rails app. I have managed to assign a category to each new pin now, but how do I set it up so that when I go look at a certain specific category (ie. "cars"), it will automatically render all the pins in that "cars" category?

I have tried the codes similar to rendering pins of a specific user (ie. "user/1">, but that didn't work for categories, so how should I do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Here are my codes

view.categories.show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>
  <b>Category</b>
  <%= @category.name %>
</h1>

<div id="pins">
  <%= render @pins %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @pins %>
```

my categories_controller.rb

```
def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @pins = @category.pins.page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @category }
    end
 end
```

And it returns the below

```
ArgumentError in Categories#show

Showing /Users/mattbook/code/starsworthy/app/views/categories/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
```

Extracted source (around line #9):

Should I generate a partial like _pin.html.erb? how should I a approach that?
Thanks in advance.

Categories_controller.rb

```
   def show
       @category = Category.find(params[:id])
       @pins = @category.pins.page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html # show.html.erb
         format.json { render json: @category }
       end
     end
```

Comment: see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: I am sorry Dax, I have gone trough it and still have no idea what I am doing wrong. Do you mind giving some pointers?

Comment: please check the value @pins i think it's nil.

Comment: Hi I Amit, I have added my categories controller code above, I do have @pins there, so I don't know where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. I found out I did have it right, don't understand why it finally works now.